# glmmadmb error: scan() expected 'a real', got 'obs'

Tags: mixed-models

The following code resemble my data:

```
uno<-rnorm(100, 0, 1)
due<-rpois(100, 2)
tre<-rnorm(100,0,1)
randomm<-as.factor(seq(from=1, to=length(uno), by=1))
data <- cbind.data.frame(uno=uno, due=due, randomm=randomm, tre=tre)
```

I need to run a mixed model with quasipoisson distribution:

```
mod <- glmmadmb(due~uno+tre+(1|randomm), data = data, family="nbinom1")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in scan(text = rr[numLines], quiet = TRUE) : 
scan() expected 'a real', got 'obs
```

What does it mean exactly? As far as I understand it has to do something with the class of my data. How to fix this?

Comment: p.s. I know it's not needed to fit a random observation effect with a quasipoisson distribution (as I did in this simple example) since one of the two methods is enough to account for overdispersion, anyway that's not the cause of the error I get. Thanks